# How to check whether the output has been redirected in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I would like to know how to check whether the standard output has been redirected or not when writting Fortran code. Because I have added encodes in the output to make them colorful, which does not work when redirection happens. So if so, the encodes should be disabled.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way that works, but may be compiler-specific, is to use a compiler extension for accessing the isatty() function (in gfortran, the ISATTY intrinsic).  Consider the following code

```
program test_isatty
  use iso_fortran_env
  write(*, *) isatty(output_unit)
end program test_isatty
```

Running it

```
$ ./isatty 
 T
$ ./isatty > foo
$ cat foo
 F
```

In case your Fortran compiler does not have an isatty extension, but comes with an extension to get the system file descriptor (fd) corresponding to a Fortran unit (in gfortran, the FNUM intrinsic), you can use that to get the fd for the standard output unit, and then you can use ISO_C_BINDING to call isatty() on the fd.

Comment: I have tried `isatty` on Ubuntu with gfortran 4.6.3, and it works well. But on Mac with gfortran 4.7.1, the program had no response.

Answer (score 3):

If the non-standard solution suggested by @Janneb doesn't appeal I'd suggest passing an argument to the Fortran program which tells it where to send its output.  The program could then determine whether or not to enable writing your encodes. If you opt for this route you can use the (Fortran 2003) intrinsic subroutine `get_command_argument`.

Comment: Thanks very much! I have thought about such solution (even in namelist), but I prefer to make such switch natural if possible. I will try 'get_command_argument' later.